# Rewrite URL for menu item CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, custom-routes

First of all - I read over 40 posts on StackOverflow and I don't find solutions to my problem...
I have an application written in CodeIgniter.

I want to rewrite URL:
http://example.com/codeigniter/en/176/terms_and_rules

On this URL:
http://example.com/codeigniter/terms_and_rules

Page "terms_and_rules" is page with my template.

My biggest problem is that I do not know what the controller is used to load these dynamic pages from the menu. I tried different for example "frontend", "blog", "news", "expert" but unfortunately no function has allowed me to this menu item 176. Probably I'm doing something wrong.

How to do it ?

Thank you for your help.

btw. I tried to use Routes.php, but without good controller I can't rewrite this URL.

Comment: i have not used this library but it might help you discover how the app is structured. http://www.keyboardninja.eu/programming/list-all-controllers-and-methods-in-codeigniter

Comment: another thing to try - enabling the codeigniter profiler.

Comment: Edit your question with posted `.htaccess` and `APPPATH . 'config/routes.php'` code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I resolved my issue.

1. I created new model that get data from database (for example from 'articles' table).
2. I created controller and load my new model.
3. I created view with template.

This is my solution ;-)